How to draw padding around Canvas compose so there is empty space of 2.dp around the circle in canvas
I have created a DOT in canvas which sits over an image
I want to add padding or empty space around the dot of 2.dp so there is a gap around the DOT.
       Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .size(11.dp)
            .constrainAs(chargerDot) {
                end.linkTo(chargerIcon.end)
                bottom.linkTo(chargerIcon.bottom)
            }
            ,onDraw = {
            drawCircle(color = Color.Green)
        })

how can I achieve that please so it looks like this

Thanks
R
Edit, I am using constraint layout to arrange DOT over the Icon
     ConstraintLayout {
        val (chargerIcon, chargerDot) = createRefs()
        val dotColor = when (chargerVisualStatus) {
            ChargerState.OFFLINE -> md_theme_dark_red
            ChargerState.ONLINE -> md_theme_dark_happy_green
            ChargerState.CONNECTING -> md_theme_dark_amber
        }
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.charger_icon),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = 2.dp, bottom = 2.dp)
                .constrainAs(chargerIcon) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                },
            tint = Color.White,
            contentDescription = null,
        )
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .size(11.dp)
            .constrainAs(chargerDot) {
                end.linkTo(chargerIcon.end)
                bottom.linkTo(chargerIcon.bottom)
            }, onDraw = {
            drawCircle(color = dotColor)
        })
    }


I hope all the contents are drawn using canvas. if yes then use BlendMode to achieve this.

no, it is just the DOT that is drawn in canvas, I just want to have round padding around the canvas DOT

You can use answer i posted with Modifier.drawWithContent and apply blendMode

Also you can draw a vector drawable inside canvas, actually inside DrawScope, as Image composable does

actually, that dot collar keeps changing, so I have kept that independent and added as canvas in a constraint layout

Canvas in jeypack Compose is Spacer with Modifier.drawWithContent. So you can just use Modifier.drawWithContent and drawContent and draw on your Composable anything you want on any position. But that part is irrelevant. What you need to is erasing bigger circle. For that, you need use BlendMode on your Composable based on any dynamic position you get

You can draw bigger transparent circle inside a layer with previous drawing. Then out of this layer draw your pinkish circle.
You can refer these answers for more details about blend/PorterDuff modes in jetpack Compose.
private fun DrawScope.drawWithLayer(block: ContentDrawScope.() -> Unit) {
    with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
        val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)
        block()
        restoreToCount(checkPoint)
    }
}


@Preview
@Composable
fun DrawBlendModeTest() {

    val painter = painterResource(R.drawable.vd_clock_alarm)
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(BlueGrey400)) {
        drawWithLayer {
            // Destination
            with(painter) {
                draw(size = Size(size.width - 100, size.width - 100))
            }

            // Source
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear,
                radius = 200f,
                center = Offset(size.width - 300f, size.width - 300f)
            )
        }

        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Red,
            radius = 150f,
            center = Offset(size.width - 300f, size.width - 300f)
        )
    }
}


Applying clear or any blend mode on any Composable
@Preview
@Composable
fun DrawBlendModeTest2() {

    val painter = painterResource(R.drawable.vd_clock_alarm)
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(1f)
            .drawWithContent {
                drawWithLayer {
                    // Destination
                    this@drawWithContent.drawContent()

                    // Source
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.Transparent,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear,
                        radius = 200f,
                        center = Offset(size.width - 300f, size.width - 300f)
                    )
                }

                drawCircle(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    radius = 150f,
                    center = Offset(size.width - 300f, size.width - 300f)
                )
            }
    )
}


Jetpack Compose Applying PorterDuffMode to Image
How to clip or cut a Composable?
